# How does the raspbery pi know which device tree blob (dtb) to load?

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, u-boot, device-tree

A raspberry pi card images includes several different dtb files in the boot partition. For example:

```
bcm2708-rpi-0-w.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-b.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-b-plus.dtb
bcm2708-rpi-cm.dtb
bcm2709-rpi-2-b.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb
bcm2710-rpi-cm3.dtb
```

When the pi boots, how does it know when dtb to select?

Comment: The kernel uses whatever **dtb** that has been loaded into memory.  The bootloader, e.g. U-Boot, decides or has defined which **dtb** file to load for the kernel.  You need to inspect the U-Boot environment to see what it does for your board.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In U-Boot file board/raspberrypi/rpi/rpi.c, function get_board_rev() the board revision is read and the dtb name is determined from the revision. The dtb file name is set in the environment variable ftdfile which can be used in a boot script to load the appropriate file which then is passed on to the operating system.

Comment: In Raspberry PI OS (debian distro), u-boot is not used. Instead, the 2nd stage bootloader (i.e., bootcode.bin file) followed by start*.elf files loads the kernel and dtb file.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the [currently accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52376940/5395338) is correct for Raspberry Pi OS - at least the "official documentation" explains it quite differently. It's further unclear why `u-boot` was part of the answer as Raspberry Pi OS doesn't use `u-boot`; and the OP didn't mention `u-boot`.

I'm not "quality police", and claim no expertise in this area - this Q&A was listed in a search result, and it seemed *a bit off*... thus, this answer.

And finally - to an answer: These various `.dtb` files contain the *"hardware definitions"* of the various hardware models of Raspberry Pi; you can see the model designation in the filename; e.g. `bcm2710-rpi-3-b-plus.dtb` designates an RPi 3B+. The `.dtb` extension is shorthand for *"device tree blob/binary"* - compiled from a `.dts` *"device tree source"* file. The hardware model is detected during the [boot process](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/raspberry-pi.html#boot-sequence), and is used to select which `.dtb` file to use, which in turn is used to set up the kernel. The Rpi hardware model designation may be found on any RPi as follows:

```bash
cat /proc/cpuinfo | grep Model
```

The "official" documentation has a much more [detailed answer](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part3.1). The documentation also has more [details on device trees in general](https://www.raspberrypi.com/documentation/computers/configuration.html#part1) if you're interested.